# Сгруппировать последовательно идущие цифры в массив

Tags: c#, linq

Есть объект `List<int>` для примера пусть будет

```
var src = new List<int> {0,1,3,5,6,7,9};
```

В исходном списке дубликаты не возможны, т.е. `{0,1,1,3,5}` не рассматривается. Список предварительно отсортирован

как написать функцию которая будет возвращать список объектов к котором будут последовательно идущие цифры, т.е. необходимо получить следующий результат:

```
var result = new List<List<int>>
{
    new List<int> {0,1},
    new List<int> {3},
    new List<int> {5,6,7},
    new List<int> {9}
};
```

мне в голову приходит только вариант сделать в цикле `for` но мне кажется что это можно сделать более *элегантней* с использованием `linq`

Comment: посмотрите как работает запррос Linq order by group. К сожалению у меня нет рукой VS чтобы показать пример.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В данном случае можно использовать метод [*Aggregate*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx), с начальным значением для аккумулятора.

```
src.Aggregate(new List<List<int>>(), (acc, cur) =>
{
    //проверяем что мы, либо зашли в первый раз, либо разница между элементами больше 1.
    if (acc.Count == 0 || cur - acc.Last().Last() > 1)
    {
        //добавляем новый список с текущим элементом
        acc.Add(new List<int> { cur });
    }
    else
    {
        //иначе добавляем в последний список
        acc.Last().Add(cur);
    }

    //возвращаем аккумулятор                
    return acc;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Это можно сделать при помощи группировки GroupBy.

```
var values = new List<int> { 0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 };
int? prev = null, first = null;
var grouped = values
    .GroupBy(
        v => v == prev + 1
            ? first += prev++ * 0
            : first = prev = v,
        (_, vs) => vs.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Есть небольшая проблема с тем, что в C# нет операции "запятая". Если бы она была, вместо странной формулы `first += prev++ * 0` можно было бы записать просто `(prev++, first)` (то есть инкрементировать первую переменную, вернуть вторую).

Разумеется, это можно записать и цивилизованно:

```
var grouped2 = values
    .GroupBy(
        v => {
            if (v == prev + 1) {
                prev++;
                return first;
            }
            else {
                return first = prev = v;
            }
        },
        (_, vs) => vs.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Правда это не будет так локанично. :)

Comment: после решения предоставленного @Grundy это кажется более сложным :)

Comment: @Bald56rus Ну там традиционный цикл, просто оформленный через Aggregate. А здесь группировка с состоянием. Разумеется, традиционный цикл легче воспринимается. Если вам в конечном счёте нужны списки, то у метода с GroupBy преимуществ не видно. Если же вам достаточно перечислений, то абсолютно вся логика умещается в одну строчку: `GroupBy(v => v == prev + 1 ? first += prev++ * 0 : first = prev = v)` (или `GroupBy(v => v == prev + 1 ? (prev++; first) : first = prev = v)` в новой версии языка).

Comment: а для чего умножение на 0? в упор не пойму

Comment: @Bald56rus Суть в том, что мне в одно выражение нужно втолкать две операции: инкрементацию одной переменной и возвращение другой. Умножение на ноль с, соответственно, суммированием с нулём позволяет использовать инкрементацию в выражении, при этом проигнорировать значение инкрементированной переменной.

Answer (score 3):

Ещё одна идея — использовать более богатый арсенал операторов LINQ.

Для начала, подключим пакет MoreLinq (консоль менеджера пакетов → `Install-Package morelinq`).

Для начала, нам нужно для каждого из элементов выяснить, нужно ли на нём заканчивать группу. Для этого нужно проконсультироваться с *предыдущим* элементом. Такую возможность нам даёт функция [`Pairwise`](http://morelinq.bitbucket.org/docs/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Pairwise__2.htm). Теперь, при этом у нас «проглотится» первый (или последний) элемент, так что его нужно добавить при помощи функции [`Prepend`](http://morelinq.bitbucket.org/docs/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Prepend__1.htm).

Покамест получаем:

```
src.Pairwise((prev, next) => new { val = next, sameGroup = next - prev == 1 })
   .Prepend(new { val = src[0], sameGroup = true })
```

Теперь, нам нужно сгруппировать последовательность в куски в зависимости от значения `sameGroup`. Такой функциональности из коробки я не нашёл, но её легко реализовать самостоятельно:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<U>> SplitBy<T, U>(
            this IEnumerable<T> source,
            Func<T, bool> mayAppend,
            Func<T, U> selector)
    {
        var chunk = new List<U>();
        foreach (var x in source)
        {
            if (!mayAppend(x))
            {
                yield return chunk;
                chunk = new List<U>();
            }
            chunk.Add(selector(x));
        }
        if (chunk.Any())
            yield return chunk;
    }
}
```

Итого:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var src = new List<int> { 0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 };
    var result = src.Pairwise((prev, next) => new { val = next, sameGroup = next - prev == 1 })
                    .Prepend(new { val = src[0], sameGroup = true })
                    .SplitBy(vs => vs.sameGroup, vs => vs.val);
    foreach (var seq in result)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", seq));
}
```

выводит

> 0 1
>   3
>   5 6 7
>   9

Comment: а `Pairwise` не тоже самое что и _Zip_?

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, почти. Zip работает для _двух_ последоватедльностей, так что `a.Zip(b, f) == a.Zip(a.Skip(1), f)`. И при этом `a` будет вычисляться дважды, а с Pairwise нет.

Comment: ну да :-) я это и имел ввиду :-) когда пробовал с Zip - что-то не срослось сразу :-) а с Aggregate - нормально :)

Comment: Я могу понять введение новых методов, когда их использование упрощает код, но когда усложняет... Вы даже мой однострочник по маловменяемости переплюнули. :)

Comment: @Discord: Ну почему же усложняет? Метод сам по себе простой, и выполняет маленькую частную задачу.