# Преобразование массива в формализованную строку

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм, строки

Существует некий массив чисел, прим. [1,2,3,4,6,7,12,14,15,16]
Необходимо преобразовать его в строку типа "1-4,6,7,12,14-16"

Как это сделать?

Comment: Что за пару часов удалось сделать? В какую сторону и как далеко ваша мысль продвинулась?

Comment: посмотрите вот этот мой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474498/179270) и ответ @Grundy, если немного подумать то я думаю можно будет добиться необходимого Вам результата

Comment: Обратная задача: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778367/218063

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сгруппировать последовательно идущие цифры в массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474498/%d0%a1%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2). Остается только к ответу @Grundy добавить `.Select(list => list.Count == 1 ? $"{list.First()}" : $"{list.First()}-{list.Last()}")` и потом поместить в `string.Join(",", ...)`

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, мое решение не очень оптимизировано, но лучше что-то чем ничего...

```
  var intArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27 };
            var orderedArray = intArray.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
            string result = String.Empty;
            int? lastNum = null;
            int? fistNum = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < orderedArray.Count; i++)
            {
                var endFlag = i == orderedArray.Count - 1;
                if (fistNum == null)
                {
                    result += orderedArray[i].ToString();
                    fistNum = orderedArray[i];
                    lastNum = orderedArray[i];
                    continue;
                }
                var flaSequnce = orderedArray[i - 1] == orderedArray[i] - 1;
                if (flaSequnce)
                {
                    lastNum = orderedArray[i];
                    if (!endFlag)
                        continue;
                }

                if (!flaSequnce && fistNum != lastNum || endFlag)
                {
                    string delim = "-";
                    if (lastNum != null)
                    {
                        delim = fistNum - lastNum == -1 ? "," : "-";
                    }
                    result += (lastNum != null ? delim + lastNum : "") + (endFlag ? "" : "," + orderedArray[i]);
                    fistNum = orderedArray[i];
                    lastNum = null;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var mass = [1,2,3,4,6,7,12,14,15,16,17, 19,20 ,22,23,24,25,26,27]; //int[]
    function massToStr(mass) {
        var str = "" + mass[0]; //string
        var count = 0; //int
        for(var i = 1 /*int*/; i < mass.length; i++){
            if(mass[i] == mass[i-1]+1){
                count++;
                if(i == mass.length-1){
                if(count < 2){
                    str += "," + mass[i];
                }else{
                    str += "-" + mass[i];
                }
                }
            }else {
                if(count == 0){
                    str += "," + mass[i];
                }else if(count < 2){
                    str += ","+ mass[i-1] + "," + mass[i];
                }else{
                    str += "-" + mass[i-1] + "," + mass[i];
                }
               count = 0;
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
    console.log(massToStr(mass));
```

Код на js(что под рукой было), выглядит страшно и не оптимизировано, но работает как нужно.

Comment: можно этот код в консоль кинуть и все заработает.

Comment: этот код запросто переписать на c#, и вместо того что бы минусовать переписал бы на c#. Что было под рукой, тем и помог

Comment: сидел, писал, что бы какой то хороший человек минуснул

Comment: c# в даном случае не собирает код js, т.е. не подходит автору вопроса. Если запросто переписать - то почему не переписали перед публикацией?

Comment: у меня тогда не было компа с visual studio. А я хотел хоть как то помочь

Comment: Цель сайта so -  создать базу знаний, т.е. каждый ответ должен подходить к вопросу. Ваш ответ не подходит к вопросу, отредактируйте его, пожайлуста, как будет время.